# What is happening when I type @+id in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Many identifiers in Android XML require the `@` prepend as a reference to values defined elsewhere in the XML.

For example

```
@drawable/transparent
@color/red
@string/hello_world
```

However, id's are quite odd in that the syntax is different:

```
@+id/my_id
```

Obviously, with the other identifiers we are making a reference to a resource which is presumable defined elsewhere, whereas for id's we are creating the identifier. Why though the syntax of `@+`? I am curious as to what this syntax really means and if there are other uses for it besides merely `@+id` (is there a `@+string`, or `@+color`?).

Answer (score 3):

> However, id's are quite odd in that the syntax is different

The syntax is *sometimes* different.

> Why though the syntax of @+?

To indicate that we are specifically creating an identifier, whereas `@id/...` means that we are referencing an identifier that should already have been defined earlier in this resource file.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/url"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@id/entry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/label"
    android:inputType="text"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/ok"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/entry"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:text="@string/ok"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ok"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/ok"
    android:text="@string/cancel"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My second references to the `label` and `entry` identifiers use `@id/`, indicating that the identifier should already have been defined earlier in the file.

Back in the days before drag-and-drop GUI builders and the like, this would help detect ID mismatches at compile time. For example, if I had typed in `@id/ernty` instead of `@id/entry`, I would get a compile error, as no `@+id/ernty` exists prior to it in the file.

> if there are other uses for it besides merely @+id

I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 0):

'@id/' : means that `my_id` is an id

'@+id/...' : means that you create an new ID.

So, when you define the ID of a view in a layout, you use `@+id/my_id`, but when you references it (for example in a android:layout_below), you use `@id/my_id`

Comment: @+... does not mean a new id. @+id specifically means a new id.